# Handle Angular.js promise error status

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

My code is like this,

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, MyService, ...) {

    MyService.getInfoFromUrl('MyUrl').then(function(result) {
        console.log("Successfully get info from URL ...");
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("Server error ...");
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

So when i test it with error path, i see
Server error ...
Undefined

What's the correct way to get error info please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to handle the server error in getInfoFromUrl() and then when error comes in your promise, call -

```
getInfoFromUrl(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    //some code to get info
    if(noErrors){ 
        resolve(Info);   //This will return value to first callback
    else if(hasErrors){
        reject(error);   //This will throw error
    }
});
}
reject(error)
```

And then use Wasiq Muhammad's code as It is.

```
MyService.getInfoFromUrl('MyUrl').success(function(result) {
    console.log("Successfully get info from URL ...");
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log("Server error ...");
    console.log(error);
});
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, MyService, ...) {

    MyService.getInfoFromUrl('MyUrl').success(function(result) {
        console.log("Successfully get info from URL ...");
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log("Server error ...");
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: angular.js:12477 TypeError: MyService.getInfoFromUrl(...).success is not a function at new <anonymous>.   Actually my post is bad, MyService is actually a factory, NOT a service. But still i don't understand why it doesn't like success.

Comment: combining answers from both of you, the "then", "catch" block worked. Still not sure why "success" is not working. Thanks very much !

Comment: which promise you are using??

Comment: $q.defer(), is this what you are asking ?